# How can ReSharper help me prevent this escaping from the constructor?

Tags: resharper

`this` escaping from the constructor is not only a design smell but also dangerous. How can ReSharper help me to prevent `this` escaping from the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible without huge computation effort. Calling instance methods from constructor, which in turn can call other methods, including methods from base types should be analysed. I.e. all places where `this` is passed implicitly. Blind warning on calling instance methods from ctor doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Well but how about *some* obvious things like passing `this` to a static method of another class (where state of `this` is accessed)  from within the ctor?